# get url from URLLoader?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there a easy / good way of getting the url from the [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) object?  It seems at least two other people ([this guy](http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg124573.html) and this [this guy](http://mail.flashcodersny.org/pipermail/flashcodersny_flashcodersny.org/2008-September/009271.html)) have wondered the same thing.  Maybe we can get an answer here on s.o.?

Comment: myLoader["url"] = "http://..."; does not work b/c http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/?p=95

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
package
{

import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public dynamic class urlURLLoader extends URLLoader
{

    private var _req:URLRequest;

    public function urlURLLoader( request:flash.net.URLRequest = null ):void
    {   super( request );
        _req = request;
    }

    public override function load( request:flash.net.URLRequest ):void
    {   _req = request;
        super.load( request );
    }

    public function get urlRequest( ):URLRequest
    {   return _req;
    }

}
```

Comment: And how would the parent Class reach out to this loader Class?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a nice approach.  The reverse approach would be to wrap your URLLoader in a class and store the info there, if you want the requesting class to be informed that a load completed and which url was successfully loaded.

You would access it something like,

```
customLoader.url="http://.....";
customLoader.onLoadDelegate = this;
customLoader.load();
```

and wait for a callback in

```
public function customLoaderComplete(url:String, data:[Object or whatever you set]) {

}
```

in the customLoader class you store the url and delegate

```
private var url:String;
private var onLoadDelegate:Object;

public function set url(_url:String):void {
  url = _url;
}

public function set onLoadDelegate(_onLoadDelegate:Object):void {
  onLoadDelegate = _onLoadDelegate;
}
```

then you create the request, URLLoader etc, and set the Event.COMPLETE listener to trigger a function which reports back to the delegate

```
public function dataLoaded(event:Event):void {

   .. parse event.target.data if needed...

    onLoadDelegate.customLoaderComplete(url, data);

}
```

If you take it a step further the top level "request issuing" class can adhere to an interface/extend a base class so you don't have to use anonymous objects.